# import files from RSA(Rational Software Architect) to EA

Tags: import, enterprise-architect, data-migration

I am trying to import RSA files (Rational Software Architect 8.04) to Sparx Enterprise Architect 11. Unfortunately, my client did not use simple types(int, char...) for his attributes. He made his own an referenced to them and called them for instance TypeBoolean, TypeChar.

When I tried to import this RSA file in EA, the Type information was missing in the generated EA Models. Has somebody had a similar issue? How can I debug this issue?

Comment: How are you moving the information between the tools? Through a third-party tool, or are you using XMI? If so, which version?

Answer (score 0):

Check the xmi file(s) you are importing into EA and make sure it contains the datatype classes (TypeBoolean, TypeChar)